# Is a referenced method definition not picked by CLR from the referenced assembly at run time?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I am observing a very strange behavior in my simple C# console application. I can't understand why CLR is working that way under the hood. Here are my code samples:

My Main program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        Console.WriteLine( emp.EmployeeName());
    }
}
```

The console application project containing the above `Main` method references another C# class library project named `CustomDataObjects`. It is as below:

```
namespace CustomDataObjects
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string GetEmployeeName()
        {
            return "Foo";
        }
    }
}
```

I build everything and it works perfectly fine. `Main` function prints "Foo" on console.

Now I changed my `CustomDataObjects` project as below. I changed the signature of `GetEmployeeName` method and introduced a new mandatory parameter named `empName`

```
namespace CustomDataObjects
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string GetEmployeeName(string empName)
        {
            return empName;
        }
    }
}
```

I did not recompile my console project after making these changes. I simply recompiled `CustomDataObjects` project after making above changes. Then, I copied the newly built `CustomDataObjects.dll` and `CustomDataObjects.pdb` files into \bin\debug directory of main console project.

Now I try to run the executable file of main console application from bin\debug directory of main console project. To my surprise it doesn't crash. If I'm not wrong, on the second run CLR should have tried to look for definition of GetEmployeeName with older signature which doesn't have any parameter and since `CustomDataObjects.dll` has changed it should observe the mismatch and cause a run-time crash. Why did it not happen this way? My console application is running on .Net v4.0

Comment: How do you launch your main console application after this tampering? By F5 from the IDE, or from a command line prompt with current directory set to its bin\debug?

Comment: I go to the directory directly and double click the exe.

Comment: @YSharp I figured this out finally. Sorry to bother but somehow an employee class with an extension method (having same signature) was declared in my main project also which was causing all the mess. So even after changing the method signature in the referenced project `CustomDataObjects`, the extension method continued to satisfy the signature demand from main method and hence was getting called. I was in shock since morning seeing this behavior. Problem solved! Monday blues :)